# Multiple if _name_ in python

Tags: python

I'd like to write a code that execute a function into two following categories:

1. Single file
2. Multiple files

What's the construct to do it? I'm thinking with multiple `if _name__`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def main(filename)
    # do something with one file.

if __name__ = '__main__'
   single_filename = "file.txt"
   main(single_filename)

# if _name__ ??
# multiple_files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']
# for file in multiple files:
#    main(file)
```

Later I'd use `argparse` to allow user to decide whether they want to run on single file or multiple files.

Comment: Why do you think checking `__name__` is an effective way to do this?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I might be wrong. Please advice what's the better way to do it?

Comment: Why not use arguments?

Comment: Have a read through the [`argparse` tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html#id1) in the documentation to understand how to parse command line arguments in Python.

Comment: How are you supposed to know whether the user wants to run it on a single file or on multiple files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly your needs, I think the best way is to test on the arguments passed into the program.

```
def main(f):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = sys.argv[1:] # the first argument is the name of the program
    for f in files:
        main(f)
```

in the cmd line, you may run

```
python bar.py file1 file2
```